# How I can calculate the limit of this sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

How I can calculate this limit:

$$\lim_{n→\infty}(\alpha^{1/(n \cdot \ln n)}-1)^{1/n}$$

where $2<α<3$ is a real number. Or at least how I can see if it is convergente sequence or not.

Comment: Is it $\alpha^{\frac{1}{ln^3}}$ ? What is $l$ ?

Comment: @ThomasProduit: How you get this!

Comment: you mean with Mathjax ? Like this: \alpha^{\frac{1}{ln^3}}

Comment: Maybe you mean: $\alpha^{1/(n \cdot \ln n)}$ which is written \alpha^{1/(n \cdot \ln n)}

Comment: @ThomasProduit: It is $nln(n)$ in the fraction.

Comment: What is inside the parenthesis will eventually become less than $1$, but stay positive. That makes it very likely that a limit exists. Whether it's $0$ or $1$ it something in-between, I'm not sure.

Comment: @Arthur: Yes, it does, but the proof is still missing.

Comment: I might have found a way without L'Hôpital, but I have to eat lunch now, I'll let you know in an hour or so.

Comment: @DER May I ask if you have any ideas for [this question of mine](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1056240/two-strictly-related-proofs-by-induction-of-inequalities)?

Comment: @VincenzoOliva: Ok I will see what I can doing with your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiplying by $\displaystyle \left(\frac{1/(n\log n)}{1/(n\log n)}\right)^{1/n} $ we get $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(\frac{1}{n\log n}\right)^{1/n} \left(\frac{\alpha^{1/(n\log n)}-1}{1/(n\log n)}\right)^{1/n}=\\\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(\frac{1}{n\log n}\right)^{1/n}\cdot \lim_{n\to \infty}\left(\frac{\alpha^{1/(n\log n)}-1}{1/(n\log n)}\right)^{1/n}.$$
We analise the latter limits separately.

For large enough $n$ we have $$\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)^{1/n}<\left(\frac{1}{n\log n}\right)^{1/n}<\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^{1/n}, $$ so by the squeeze theorem, $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(\frac{1}{n\log n}\right)^{1/n}=1. $$

As to the second limit, let $\displaystyle m=\frac{1}{n\log n}$ to obtain $$\lim_{m\to 0}_{n\to \infty} \left(\frac{\alpha^m-1}{m}\right)^{1/n}=\lim_{n\to \infty}(\log\alpha)^{1/n}=1.$$
Thus we conclude $$\lim_{n→\infty}\left(\alpha^{1/(n \cdot \log n)}-1\right)^{1/n}=1. $$

Answer (score 1):

Let $\varphi(n)=\left(f(n)-1\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}=\exp\left[\frac{\log\left(f(n)-1\right)}{n}\right]$ where $f(n)=\alpha^{\frac{1}{n\log n}}\to 1$ as $n\to\infty$.
We have 
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log (f(n)-1)}{n}\stackrel{\tiny l'Hospital}{=}\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{f'(n)}{f(n)-1}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{-\frac{\log\alpha(1+\log n)}{n^2\log^2 n}f(n)}{f(n)-1}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{-\log\alpha}{n^2\log n}=0
$$
so that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\varphi(n)=1.
$$

EDIT: if you can use Tayolor's expansion, you have $f(n)\sim 1+\frac{\log\alpha}{n\log n}$ so that $\log\varphi(n)\sim\frac{\log\log\alpha-\log n-\log\log n}{n}\to 0$ and $\varphi(n)\to 1$.

Comment: @ alexjo: but the l'Hospital rule applied only for the cases $0/0$. In our case there is not.

Comment: @DER Also for $\infty/\infty$. See for example [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule)

Comment: @ alexjo: Yes, and thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be $1$, judging from the graphs of
$$y=(\alpha^{-x\ln x}-1)^x$$
with $x$ ranging from $0.001$ to $.1$ in steps of $0.001$. (Think of $x$ as $1/n$.) Tried with big and small values of $\alpha$ (ranging between $1.000000001$ and $10^{20}$).

The question now is, how to prove it...

Comment: @ Heimdall: We can makes the restriction $2<α<3$

Comment: @DER Well, for those $\alpha$ the graph was almost a flat line. That's why I observed more extreme values, too.